# Onlistitemclick not Working

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I am loading an array into a listview and when I click on the list item, I want to display the item in a textview within the same activity.  The list is currently loading, but the program crashes when an item is clicked.  Any thoughts why?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WordList extends ListActivity {
    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
     * 
    */
    //public final static String TERM_EXTRA="com.myapp._word";
    //public final static String DEF_EXTRA="com.myapp._pic";

    TextView selection;
    ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
        Resources res=getResources();
        String[] words = res.getStringArray(R.array.words);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,words));
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        selection.setText(words.get(position).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `words.get(position).toString()` returns null if you did not append any object to "words" which is an ArrayList as declared this way:

```
ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>();
```

`"String[] words"` is not what you are using in `onListItemClick`, but `"ArrayList<String> words"` is.

Edit:

Comment the arraylist, and define "String[] words" outside of onCreate.

```
//ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>();
String[] words;
```

Then in your onListItemClick;

```
selection.setText(words[position]);
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Good catch +1. I hadn't spotted that.

Comment: So should I not be using ArrayList<String>?